# Cordova-SQlite-Storage plugin for iOS App Group Support

Tags: sqlite, ionic-framework, xamarin.ios, cordova-sqlite-storage

I am using the **Cordova-SQLite-Storage** plugin for my **ios ionic application**. I want to access the **SQLite** database from the **Xamarin.iOS** application. In **Cordova-SQLite-Storage** plugin, database path for ios is private so **Xamarin.iOS** cannot access the database. I have implemented app grouping and the same group name is given for **ionic ios** application and **Xamarin.iOS** application. Now my requirement is to store the **Cordova SQLite** database on the **ionic** application using the app group and access that database from **Xamarin.iOS** native application. I have referred many sites but I did not get any correct solution for this. Please help me to do this.